# Popular software recommendation question - acceptable?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

The following question: [What tools can be used to facilitate code reviews after commits?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/39122/what-tools-can-be-used-to-facilitate-code-reviews-after-commits)

It has quite a few upvotes, many answers, and over 2k views. I didn't think this'd be the kind of acceptable question, yet it seems accepted. 2 moderators stumbled upon the question and didn't say anything.

Am I wrong in voting to close this?

Comment: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: That question was quite old … and policies on what is on-topic change over time. Thanks for finding and closing this clearly off-topic question!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No you are not wrong to vote to close.

If you look at the dates when the moderators last interacted with the question you'll see that it was quite a while ago now - certainly before the "software recommendations" close reason came into force, and at a time when we thought such questions were OK.

The need for that close reason is apparent as there was a new spam answer that had been added to the question.

I've deleted the spam and closed the question.

Comment: Oh indeed, I forgot to look at the date. My bad! It was on frontpage, so I didn't think much more of it.